# How do you tell the difference between 決行 and 欠航?

Tags: kanji, pronunciation, pitch-accent, multiple-readings, context

So apparently
決行-けっこう (to carry out)
and
欠航-けっこう (cancelled)
are pronounced the same way? Or does one of them have a different pitch accent pattern? At least Google translate pronounced them the same.
This seems problematic for a situation like the following, since you can't tell from context:
https://youtu.be/J2vVPpbEdH0?t=21

Comment: At least for me, "決行" is definitely not the first word that comes to mind in a situation like this...

Comment:  That video is hilarious.  In those kind of situations, I think the only way to get the point across is to 言い換える.

Comment: In actual Japanese, 決行 = "to daringly 実行". A ship cannot be 実行-ed so there's no chance to confuse this pair.

Answer (score 3):

決行 and 欠航 are pronounced the same, but you *can* tell which is used from the context. Simply, 決行 is not a word used in a situation like the one in that video. Note that the person on the right is supposed to be a traveler who doesn't speak Japanese like a native speaker.

決行 means holding a public/social event or carrying out a plan/operation determinedly despite some obstacle (typically bad weather). Here "event" includes a live concert, a sport game, a competition, a strike action, a military operation, and so on, but not a departure of a ferry/airplane.

Answer (score 0):

決行 (けっこう{LHHH}) and 欠航 (けっこう{LHHH}) are both of level pitch. No other options are offered by NHK日本語発音アクセント辞典 or 大辞林.